# How can I use boto to stream a file out of Amazon S3 to Rackspace Cloudfiles?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, rackspace, cloudfiles

I'm copying a file from S3 to Cloudfiles, and I would like to avoid writing the file to disk.  The Python-Cloudfiles library has an object.stream() call that looks to be what I need, but I can't find an equivalent call in boto.  I'm hoping that I would be able to do something like:

```
shutil.copyfileobj(s3Object.stream(),rsObject.stream())
```

Is this possible with boto (or I suppose any other s3 library)?

Comment: The [smart_open](https://github.com/piskvorky/smart_open) Python library does that (both for reading and writing).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Key object in boto, which represents on object in S3, can be used like an iterator so you should be able to do something like this:

```
>>> import boto
>>> c = boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket = c.lookup('garnaat_pub')
>>> key = bucket.lookup('Scan1.jpg')
>>> for bytes in key:
...   write bytes to output stream
```

Or, as in the case of your example, you could do:

```
>>> shutil.copyfileobj(key, rsObject.stream())
```

Comment: S3.Object is not iterable anymore.

Comment: S3.object is still iterable , but with S3object['body'].iter_lines() so something like this

Answer (score 89):

Other answers in this thread are related to boto, but S3.Object is not iterable anymore in boto3. So, the following DOES NOT WORK, it produces an `TypeError: 's3.Object' object is not iterable` error message:

```
s3 = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=my_profile).resource('s3')
s3_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=my_bucket, key=my_key)

with io.FileIO('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in s3_obj:
        file.write(i)
```

In boto3, the contents of the object is available at `S3.Object.get()['Body']` which is an iterable since version [1.9.68](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/3c024441a94b7c6661ce28f7a283d2878115c81a/CHANGELOG.rst#1968) but previously wasn't. Thus the following will work for the latest versions of boto3 but not earlier ones:

```
body = s3_obj.get()['Body']
with io.FileIO('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in body:
        file.write(i)
```

So, an alternative for older boto3 versions is to use the read method, but this loads the WHOLE S3 object in memory which when dealing with large files is not always a possibility:

```
body = s3_obj.get()['Body']
with io.FileIO('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in body.read():
        file.write(i)
```

But the `read` method allows to pass in the `amt` parameter specifying the number of bytes we want to read from the underlying stream. This method can be repeatedly called until the whole stream has been read:

```
body = s3_obj.get()['Body']
with io.FileIO('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
    while file.write(body.read(amt=512)):
        pass
```

Digging into `botocore.response.StreamingBody` code one realizes that the underlying stream is also available, so we could iterate as follows:

```
body = s3_obj.get()['Body']
with io.FileIO('sample.txt', 'w') as file:
    for b in body._raw_stream:
        file.write(b)
```

While googling I've also seen some links that could be use, but I haven't tried:

- [WrappedStreamingBody](https://gist.github.com/debedb/2e5cbeb54e43f031eaf0)
- [Another related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570226/how-to-use-botocore-response-streamingbody-as-stdin-pipe)
- [An issue in boto3 github to request StreamingBody is a proper stream](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/426) - which has been closed!!!

Comment: Very useful answer. Thanks @smallo. I appreciate that you exposed the private __raw_stream which is what I think most people are looking for.

Comment: If I pass around this body `StreamingBody`, does this mean the HTTP connection isn't terminated? Or is the streaming body buffered up?

Comment: Not sure if this was available when this answer was written, but `botocore.response.StreamingBody` now exposes `iter_chunks` and `iter_lines` for this purpose.

Answer (score 21):

I figure at least some of the people seeing this question will be like me, and will want a way to stream a file from boto line by line (or comma by comma, or any other delimiter). Here's a simple way to do that:

```
def getS3ResultsAsIterator(self, aws_access_info, key, prefix):        
    s3_conn = S3Connection(**aws_access)
    bucket_obj = s3_conn.get_bucket(key)
    # go through the list of files in the key
    for f in bucket_obj.list(prefix=prefix):
        unfinished_line = ''
        for byte in f:
            byte = unfinished_line + byte
            #split on whatever, or use a regex with re.split()
            lines = byte.split('\n')
            unfinished_line = lines.pop()
            for line in lines:
                yield line
```

@garnaat's answer above is still great and 100% true. Hopefully mine still helps someone out.

Comment: split on other both types line endings with: `lines = re.split(r'[\n\r]+', byte)` - helpful for CSV files exported from Excel

Comment: one more note: I had to add `yield unfinished_line` after the `for byte in f:` loop was complete, otherwise the last line would not get processed

Comment: Is there a good reason why this is not part of the Boto3 API? If not, should one submit a pull request to fix this? I'd be super down for knocking something like it up!

Comment: @Eli yes I'll knock a generator-based thing up which will chunk the stream online by a given delimiter? Super keen to smash that out!

Comment: Makes sense to me, especially the delimiter part. something like `getS3ResultsAsIterator(self, aws_access_info, key, prefix, delimiter="\n"):`

Comment: Lets see how this pull request goes over at botocore: https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1034

Answer (score 13):

Botocore's `StreamingBody` has an `iter_lines()` method:

https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.iter_lines

So:

```
import boto3
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')
iterator = s3r.Object(bucket, key).get()['Body'].iter_lines()

for line in iterator:
    print(line)
```

Comment: this doesn't continue the stream it just gets one chunk

Comment: @cosbor11 You can specify the chunk size as you need: `.iter_lines(chunk_size=1024)`

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution of wrapping streaming body:

```
import io
class S3ObjectInterator(io.RawIOBase):
    def __init__(self, bucket, key):
        """Initialize with S3 bucket and key names"""
        self.s3c = boto3.client('s3')
        self.obj_stream = self.s3c.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body']

    def read(self, n=-1):
        """Read from the stream"""
        return self.obj_stream.read() if n == -1 else self.obj_stream.read(n)
```

Example usage:

```
obj_stream = S3ObjectInterator(bucket, key)
for line in obj_stream:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other options, [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) is a utility for streaming large files in Python, and it makes work extremely easy.

Here are two examples:

```py
import boto3
from smart_open import open

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="xxx",
    aws_secret_access_key="xxx",
)
client = session.client('s3')

for line in open(
    "s3://my-bucket/my-file.txt",
    transport_params=dict(client=client),
):
    print(line)
```

For compressed file:

```py
import boto3
from smart_open import open

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id="xxx",
    aws_secret_access_key="xxx",
)
client = session.client('s3')

for line in open(
    "s3://my-bucket/my-file.txt.gz",
    encoding="utf-8",
    transport_params=dict(client=client),
):
    print(line)
```