# Can Rackspace Cloud Files be accessed using S3 (AWS) APIs?

Tags: api, amazon-s3, rackspace-cloud

I got to know that Rackspace Cloud Files is based on OpenStack Object Storage service (Swift).

As OpenStack allows configuring/manipulating object storage using S3 APIs through swift3
http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-object-storage/admin/content/configuring-openstack-object-storage-with-s3_api.html
I am thinking whether Rackspace Cloud Files provides S3 API support as well. I have a client written for Amazon Web Services using S3 RESTful APIs so was thinking to reuse it for Rackspace Cloud Files as well.

Comment: in addition to what jnoller bellow suggests, boto also supports S3 and CloudFiles as well as Google Cloud Storage.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624900/how-can-i-use-boto-to-stream-a-file-out-of-amazon-s3-to-rackspace-cloudfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 plugin for Swift is not deployed as part of Rackspace Cloud Files (most production deploys of openstack don't deploy it by default). However, if you want better flexibility in the app, you can use a cross cloud toolkit such as libcloud (python), fog (ruby), jclouds (java), pkgcloud (node/js). This means you can use a simpler abstraction and support multiple providers within your application.