# Read a file line by line from S3 using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a csv file in S3 and I'm trying to read the header line to get the size (these files are created by our users so they could be almost any size). Is there a way to do this using boto? I thought maybe I could us a python BufferedReader, but I can't figure out how to open a stream from an S3 key. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Would `key.size` not work for you? Returns the key size in bytes. If you want the header, you could also stream the first chunk only, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625197/786559 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that boto has a `read()` function that can do this. Here's some code that works for me:

```
>>> import boto
>>> from boto.s3.key import Key
>>> conn = boto.connect_s3('ap-southeast-2')
>>> bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-name')
>>> k = Key(bucket)
>>> k.key = 'filename.txt'
>>> k.open()
>>> k.read(10)
'This text '
```

The call to `read(n)` returns the next n bytes from the object.

Of course, this won't automatically return "the header line", but you could call it with a large enough number to return the header line at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks, John. This was going to be my fallback solution if I couldn't find a way to stream the file. I'll just take a guess about the max size of the header and go from there.

Comment: @John Rotenstein - do not you have to close the file after read()?

Answer (score 39):

Here's a solution which actually streams the data line by line:

```
from io import TextIOWrapper
from gzip import GzipFile
...

# get StreamingBody from botocore.response
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
# if gzipped
gzipped = GzipFile(None, 'rb', fileobj=response['Body'])
data = TextIOWrapper(gzipped)

for line in data:
    # process line
```

Comment: The gzip requirement wasn't in the initial question, but this is exactly what I needed for my use case.  Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a much neater way to go than using an external package. Sad that 1) your answer did not get checked as the actual answer and 2) that the smart_open solution got so many ups.

Comment: It does not work if we don't use `GzipFile` to decompress it, as `StreamingBody` does not have a `readable` property which `TextIOWrapper` requires

Comment: this should be the accepted answer... smart_open appears to be significantly slower: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/issues/457
in my own testing files stream about 5x faster using the approach described in this answer than using smart_open. it's a super cool library but doesn't seem to be up to par for this particular use case.

Answer (score 34):

You may find https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smart_open useful for your task.

From documentation:

```
for line in smart_open.smart_open('s3://mybucket/mykey.txt'):
    print line
```

Comment: this is so much easier ! And is supports gzipped files by default !

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Michael Korbakov This is giving me an exception TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: What is the cost? Do you end up downloading the entire file just to read a few  lines?

Comment: Using external libraries is usually bad practice -  you want to have minimum dependencies so that you can upgrade and move forward easy.

Comment: @IvailoBardarov is it possible to read data from S3 with avoiding saving all the bytes in memory, without smart_open?

Comment: @AmundeepSingh Yes, you just do s3.get_object(), then passing the response["Body"] to a io.TextIOWrapper and then read it by line by line. The memory will stay constant based on the buffers set. Here is how I read compressed gz files and read them line by line https://gist.github.com/gudata/da5d0553a309836d998a56c73c60575c It is a few lines of code using only whats in python and boto

Comment: What about .dat or any complex file read? Can you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287301/how-to-read-dat-file-from-aws-s3-using-mdfreader ?

Answer (score 32):

I know it's a very old question.

But as for now, we can just use `s3_conn.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].iter_lines()`

Comment: yeah if this question were asked today this and .iter_chunks() would be the answer +1

Comment: The `iter_lines()`  method is part of botocore.response package: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html

Comment: One question/concern I have: Does `iter_lines` make another GET request every time it needs the next chunk?  (Also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60422708)

Comment: @Dominus.Vobiscum It loads a fixed chunk size(in bytes) for each request, if there is another line in the loaded content cache, the `__next__` call to the generator returns it, otherwise it will make another request until there is no remaining content.  See https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/dfda41c08e3ed5354dce9f958b6db06e6cce99ed/botocore/response.py#L135-L148

Answer (score 15):

The [`codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.getreader) in the stdlib provides a simple way to encode a stream of bytes into a stream of text and provides a generator to retrieve this text line-by-line.  It can be used with S3 without much hassle:

```py
import codecs

import boto3


s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3_object = s3.Object('my-bucket', 'a/b/c.txt')
line_stream = codecs.getreader("utf-8")

for line in line_stream(s3_object.get()['Body']):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 9):

With boto3 you can access a raw stream and read line by line.
Just note raw stream is a private property for some reason

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxx', aws_secret_access_key='xxx')
obj = s3.Object('bucket name', 'file key')

obj.get()['Body']._raw_stream.readline() # line 1
obj.get()['Body']._raw_stream.readline() # line 2
obj.get()['Body']._raw_stream.readline() # line 3...
```

Comment: As is hinted by `_raw_stream` property beginning with an underscore, this is not how you should access the stream contents. They can be read in entirety by calling `obj.get()["body"].read()` or iterated as a generator with `obj.get()["body"].iter_lines()`

Comment: For some python APIs, this is the only way to go (e.g. `pickle.load` which expects to find both `.read()` and `.readline()` defined on its argument)

Comment: @Alex it's `obj.get()["Body"].read()` note the capital B in Body

Answer (score 7):

Using boto3:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(BUCKET, key)
for line in obj.get()['Body']._raw_stream:
    # do something with line
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read multiple files (line by line) with a specific bucket prefix (i.e., in a "subfolder") you can do this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='<key_id>', aws_secret_access_key='<access_key>')

    bucket = s3.Bucket('<bucket_name>')
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='<your prefix>'):
        for line in obj.get()['Body'].read().splitlines():
            print(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

Here lines are bytes so I am decoding them; but if they are already a string, you can skip that.

Answer (score 2):

The most dynamic and low cost way to read the file is to read each byte until you find the number of lines you need.

```
line_count = 0
line_data_bytes = b''

while line_count < 2 :

    incoming = correlate_file_obj['Body'].read(1)
    if incoming == b'\n':
        line_count = line_count + 1

    line_data_bytes = line_data_bytes + incoming

logger.debug("read bytes:")
logger.debug(line_data_bytes)

line_data = line_data_bytes.split(b'\n')
```

You won't need to guess about header size if the header size can change, you won't end up downloading the whole file, and you don't need 3rd party tools. Granted you need to make sure the line delimeter in your file is correct and you are reading the right number of bytes to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on kooshywoosh's answer: using TextIOWrapper (which is very useful) on a StreamingBody from a plain binary file directly isn't possible, as you'll get the following error:

```
"builtins.AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'readable'"
```

However, you can use the following hack mentioned in [this](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/879) long standing issue on botocore's github page, and define a very simple wrapper class around StreamingBody:

```
from io import RawIOBase
...

class StreamingBodyIO(RawIOBase):
"""Wrap a boto StreamingBody in the IOBase API."""
def __init__(self, body):
    self.body = body

def readable(self):
    return True

def read(self, n=-1):
    n = None if n < 0 else n
    return self.body.read(n)
```

Then, you can simply use the following code:

```
from io import TextIOWrapper
...

# get StreamingBody from botocore.response
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
data = TextIOWrapper(StreamingBodyIO(response))
for line in data:
    # process line
```

Comment: Also, remember "from io import RawIOBase"