# Read a csv file from aws s3 using boto and pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, amazon-s3, boto

I have already read through the answers available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818341/how-to-read-a-csv-file-from-an-s3-bucket-using-pandas-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618468/read-a-file-line-by-line-from-s3-using-boto) and these do not help.

I am trying to read a `csv` object from `S3` bucket and have been able to successfully read the data using the following code.

```
srcFileName="gossips.csv"
def on_session_started():
  print("Starting new session.")
  conn = S3Connection()
  my_bucket = conn.get_bucket("randomdatagossip", validate=False)
  print("Bucket Identified")
  print(my_bucket)
  key = Key(my_bucket,srcFileName)
  key.open()
  print(key.read())
  conn.close()

on_session_started()
```

However, if I try to read the same object using pandas as a data frame, I get an error. The most common one being `S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden`

```
def on_session_started2():
  print("Starting Second new session.")
  conn = S3Connection()
  my_bucket = conn.get_bucket("randomdatagossip", validate=False)
  #     url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/randomdatagossip/gossips.csv"
  #     urllib2.urlopen(url)

  for line in smart_open.smart_open('s3://my_bucket/gossips.csv'):
     print line
  #     data = pd.read_csv(url)
  #     print(data)

on_session_started2()
```

What am I doing wrong? I am on python 2.7 and cannot use Python 3.

Comment: Don't use those outdated example without knowing what you are doing. Go check out boto3

Comment: Since you're already using [`smart_open`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open), just do `data = pd.read_csv(smart_open.smart_open('s3://randomdatagossip/gossips.csv'))`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is what I have done to successfully read the `df` from a `csv` on S3.

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3

bucket = "yourbucket"
file_name = "your_file.csv"

s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
# 's3' is a key word. create connection to S3 using default config and all buckets within S3

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file_name) 
# get object and file (key) from bucket

initial_df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body']) # 'Body' is a key word
```

Comment: This does not work with recent versions of pandas. See my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/46323684/1451649 that works for pandas 0.20.3

Comment: How ca I load only a subset of the csv instead of the whole file?

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import io

s3_file_key = 'data/test.csv'
bucket = 'data-bucket'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_file_key)

initial_df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

Comment: Works with parquet as well as long as it is a single parquet file in the s3 key: df = pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))

Comment: Finally found something that worked out of the box for me. Thank you!

Comment: What is s3_file_key?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to use pandas read_sql and pyathena:

```
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd

conn = connect(s3_staging_dir='s3://bucket/folder',region_name='region')
df = pd.read_sql('select * from database.table', conn)
```