# Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

while reading **csv** file from s3 getting **segmentation fault** error in AWS Lambda function.

Note: code is working, but for some files getting this error

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=key)

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU9q7.png)

{
"errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
"errorMessage": "RequestId: 34abfc3f-dff3-342c2-89f8-0346f6ab3bf Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault"
}

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46323684/322912) says you should also `decode()`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for the reply!!
with the decode() as well getting same error.

Comment: How much RAM do you have assigned to your function and how big is the file that you're downloading and reading here?

Comment: @pgrzesik Thanks for your time!!
I am using Memory 1024MB, Ephemeral storage 512MB, Timeout 15min0sec.
file size range is 100kb to 150kb.