# s3fs custom endpoint url

Tags: python, boto3

How do I pass a custom endpoint url to `s3fs.S3FileSystem` ?

I've tried:

```
kwargs = {'endpoint_url':"https://s3.wasabisys.com",
          'region_name':'us-east-1'}
self.client = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
                                secret=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                                use_ssl=True,
                                **kwargs)
```

However I get the error:

```
  File "s3fs/core.py", line 215, in connect
    **self.kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'endpoint_url'
```

I've also tried passing kwargs as the parameter `config_kwargs` and `s3_additional_kwargs` with similar errors.

I can verify `boto3` is working with the following:

```
client = boto3.client("s3",
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        endpoint_url="https://s3.wasabisys.com",
        use_ssl=True,
        region_name="us-east-1", 
        api_version=None,verify=None, config=None)
```

Comment: From the documentation, it states : `client_kwargs : dict of parameters for the boto3 client`. Have you tried setting `client_kwargs` with `endpoint_url `?

Comment: @shuwnyuantee yes, I stated that in my question above too.

Comment: I'm also able to get `fs-s3fs` to work, I think this deserves a bug report on their github

Comment: mind to share your fix?

Comment: @shuwnyuantee see the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an undocumented parameter in the current verison `client_kwargs={'endpoint_url': 'https:...'}` which is the desired one.

https://github.com/dask/s3fs/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be used for this question but is relatable to this in some cases.

Though the question has been answered, I want to brief you on an alternative approach that might be helpful to a lot of us. We can mount a s3 bucket of AWS or other implementations locally to a folder. My use case was to use the AWS S3 bucket as a local folder, so I created a folder locally named `minio-faceid` and mounted it with the AWS S3 bucket `faceid`.

Assuming you are using a Linux-based distribution namely Ubuntu. First, install `s3fs` using this command `sudo apt install s3fs`, then save your access key and secret access key for S3 like this

```
echo access_key:secret_access_key > ${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs && chmod 600 ${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs
```

Lastly, mount your AWS S3 bucket to your local folder this way

```
s3fs faceid /minio-faceid -o passwd_file=${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs -o url=http://your_s3_url/ -o use_path_request_style
```

Now read and write from your `minio-faceid` local folder, which will be synced to your S3 bucket `faceid`.

Comment: I think you are answering a different question here