# "errorMessage": "'Session' object has no attribute 'region_id'" in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Code is below

```
import boto3
import json
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                   credentials.secret_key,
                   session.region_id, 'es',
                   session_token=credentials.token)
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://xx.es.amazonaws.com'],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    es.cluster.health()
    #es.indices.delete(index='test', ignore=[400, 404])

    es.indices.create(index='test', ignore=400)
    r = [{'id': '1', 'data': 'Health'},
 {'id': '2', 'data': 'countries'},
 {'id': '3', 'data': 'currency'},
 {'id': '4', 'data': 'language'}]
    for e in enumerate(r):
        es.index(index="test", body=e[1])
        result = es.search(index="test", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
    return{
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body':result
    }
```

I was getting proper out last day

Today i got the error below

```py
{
  "errorMessage": "'Session' object has no attribute 'region_id'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 702, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 783, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 15, in <module>\n    session.region_id, 'es',\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should [be](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session):

```
session.region_name
```

not `session.region_id`.

Comment: @Nons As you see in the docs linked, there is no `region_id` in session. I don't know how it could have worked before.

Comment: can you answer this below. Thanks in advance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63109212/how-to-push-the-data-from-dynamodb-through-stream

Comment: I tried the question in below link, same issue I got as like the questionnaire. can you check once please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455543/how-to-get-the-column-names-in-redshift-using-python-boto3

Comment: If anyone wants help for local folder mounting to s3 bucket, can go through this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77369021/7195890