# How to get the column names in redshift using Python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, boto3

I want to get the column names in redshift using python boto3

1. Creaed Redshift Cluster
2. Insert Data into it
3. Configured Secrets Manager
4. Configure SageMaker Notebook

Open the Jupyter Notebook wrote the below code

```
import boto3
import time    
client = boto3.client('redshift-data')    
response = client.execute_statement(ClusterIdentifier = "test", Database= "dev", SecretArn= "{SECRET-ARN}",Sql= "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='dev' AND `TABLE_NAME`='dojoredshift'")
```

I got the response but there is no table schema inside it

Below is the code i used to connect I am getting timed out

```
import psycopg2
HOST = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
PORT = 5439
USER = 'aswuser'
PASSWORD = 'Password1!'
DATABASE = 'dev'
def db_connection():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST,port=PORT,user=USER,password=PASSWORD,database=DATABASE)
    return conn
```

How to get the ip address  go to `https://ipinfo.info/html/ip_checker.php`

pass your hostname of redshiftcluster `xx.xx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com`  or you can see in cluster page itself

I got the error while running above code

> > OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
> > Is the server running on host "x.xx.xx..xx" and accepting
> > TCP/IP connections on port 5439?

Comment: The blog i followed to create cluster and table. https://aws-dojo.com/excercises/excercise19/

Comment: i tried with https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=308979 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I fixed with the code, and add the above the rules

```
import boto3
import psycopg2
 
# Credentials can be set using different methodologies. For this test,
# I ran from my local machine which I used cli command "aws configure"
# to set my Access key and secret access key
 
client = boto3.client(service_name='redshift',
                      region_name='us-east-1')
#
#Using boto3 to get the Database password instead of hardcoding it in the code
#
cluster_creds = client.get_cluster_credentials(
                         DbUser='awsuser',
                         DbName='dev',
                         ClusterIdentifier='redshift-cluster-1',
                         AutoCreate=False)
 
try:
    # Database connection below that uses the DbPassword that boto3 returned
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host = 'redshift-cluster-1.cvlywrhztirh.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
                port = '5439',
                user = cluster_creds['DbUser'],
                password = cluster_creds['DbPassword'],
                database = 'dev'
                )
    # Verifies that the connection worked
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    ver = results[0]
    if (ver is None):
        print("Could not find version")
    else:
        print("The version is " + ver)
 
except:
    logger.exception('Failed to open database connection.')
    print("Failed")
```