# Load file into SQL Server from S3 using BCP or Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-s3, boto, bcp

Is there any effective way to import csv/text file from Amazon S3 bucket into MS SQL Server 2012/2014 by BCP or Python (without using SSIS)?

I have found this answer: [Read a file line by line from S3 using boto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618468/read-a-file-line-by-line-from-s3-using-boto) , but I am not sure whether it will be effective and secure way in compare with downloading file and then using BCP.

Thanks.