# Does iterating through a file in S3 using boto3's StreamingBody.iter_lines() count as a GET request for each line?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm working on something where I am trying to access some data stored in a large CSV file in S3 via boto3. I'm considering iterating through the data line by line for memory sake, using:

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
iterator = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='my-bucket', Key='my-key')['Body'].iter_lines()

for line in iterator:
    foo(line)
```

This works on the toy data I've been testing with, but the full dataset is over 70 million rows. My question is if using this method to iterate through the data will actually send off 70 million separate requests (and incurs charges by AWS per 70 million times more than were I to read the entire file in at once)? Or does it count a single request?

I don't have a great understanding of the underlying mechanism boto3 is using to access the data in a StreamingBody class, and have had difficulty finding information on it, including in the boto3 documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/response.py#L30

Comment: I believe the `get_object()` method is one call to retrieve the streaming body and that's it. you've already gotten it and saved it to the `iterator` variable so from there on it's not calling to AWS. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it loads a fixed chunk size(in bytes) for each request, if there is another line in the loaded content cache, the `__next__` call to the generator returns it, otherwise, it will make another request until there is no remaining content.  See https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/dfda41c08e3ed5354dce9f958b6db06e6cce99ed/botocore/response.py#L135-L148

So how many requests it makes depends on the file size and the chunk size, not related to the size of each line, it should work well for your case.