# Read lines between ranges from s3 file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a s3 csv file in aws-s3 bucket. I want to read only ranges of lines from the file instead of whole file as it is.

My goal here is, to get the content of the file in paginated way in the UI application as a tabulated form.

I read that `Range` option is present in s3.getObject from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_RequestSyntax).

But I do not need byte ranges but I need line ranges. Ex: (1-100, similar to pagination)

Is there a way that we can do this using NodeJS?

Comment: No, S3 doesn't support line ranges.

Comment: Yeah I agree that S3 does not support it directly. But is there a indirect way to do it?
something similar to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39745836/2173020

Comment: The reason because, the file size is unimaginably huge and I do not want to load everything. So looking around some alternatives

Comment: Have you tried Amazon S3 Select? It supports CSV file.

Comment: @jellycsc, I never heard about S3 select. Could you please point me to some examples?

Comment: No problem. Here is a pretty well-written [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/querying-data-without-servers-or-databases-using-amazon-s3-select/) to get started.

Comment: Thank you so much @jellycsc, this is really helpful.

Comment: Any chance of adding a "line number" to the CSV file as another column? You could then select the rows based on that row number.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use S3 select (add a new column row_index to limit the number of rows) or Athena to query the CSV files.

S3 select program to print 1000 rows from a CSV file

```
import boto3
S3_BUCKET = 'bucket-name'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

r = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        Key='filename.csv',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression="select \"column\" from s3object s where row_index >= 1 and row_index <= 1000,
        InputSerialization={'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}},
        OutputSerialization={'CSV': {}},
)

for event in r['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
```

Using Athena

You can simply upload a CSV file in Athena. It's pretty straight forward to upload files to Athena. Then you can query limited set of data from select query.

```
SELECT * FROM table limit 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

S3 select_object_content does not support row_number() function. If you have any unique/range column in your CSV use that column to perform select query to get lines/rows for particular range. But never forget to cast range column into integer in your query otherwise it will consider as string.

```
import boto3
S3_BUCKET = 'bucket-name'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

r = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        Key='filename.csv',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression="select * from s3object s where CAST(row_index as INT) >= 1 and CAST(row_index as INT) <= 100",
        InputSerialization={'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}},
        OutputSerialization={'CSV': {}},
)

for event in r['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
```

Answer (score 0):

No s3 does not support this currently .

You will have to extract the whole file and  then you can perform the filters over it using fast-csv module.

You can use skip-rows and max-rows of this module to form a range .

https://c2fo.io/fast-csv/docs/parsing/options

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your lines into their respective bytes . There is an npm module that converts to bytes