# Decoding issue when downloading from an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to receive a CSV file from an Amazon S3 bucket like this:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='BUCKET_NAME', Key='FILE_NAME')
data = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
```

But this is what I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 10: invalid start byte
```

I thought I got the encoding of the file wrong, so I ran `file FILE_NAME.csv` and got UTF-8. I have also tried latin-1 and some other encodings, but all of them give me gibberish. Any help is appreciated, and thank you all!

Comment: Try `obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='BUCKET_NAME', Key='FILE_NAME', ResponseContentType='text/csv')` - does that work?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Unfortunately, it's not working. This is the error I'm getting:  
```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: invalid continuation byte```

Comment: Is this a valid CSV file? Does it open correctly if you download it via the AWS console?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It's a valid CSV file. I can download it using AWSCLI and the console

Comment: And it opens up as a CSV file?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes and all the data is in there

Comment: Hmm - can you please split out the `data = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()` command and let us know the contents in `obj['Body']`, `obj['Body'].read()` and `obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')` separately? I feel like the `obj['Body']` might perhaps be empty? Not sure.

Comment: Ah wait - what's the compression set for the CSV file in the S3 console?

Comment: Also try `data = obj['Body'].iter_lines()`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary the output of ```obj['body']```: ```<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x00000161BD0543D0>```

output of ```obj['body'].read()```: ```\xc7)D\x94\xcc:9\x01\xb4\x1f\xa9\x01\x93G\xb6\x84Dv\xdf\x9b\xd8\xd0uHp<\xfe\xfb\xee\xb4\xea\x83\x1\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xf4\x8eKS\x15+\xf8\xeew\x02\x00\x00\x``` (this is parts of the output)

output of ```obj['body'].read().decode('utf-8')```: ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: invalid continuation byte```

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Not sure how I can find out what the compression set of the file is

Comment: Does `data = obj['Body'].iter_lines()` work? - also please add the outputs to the question if you don't mind and the fact that it is indeed a valid CSV etc. as comments get lost thank you

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Will do! This is the output for ```data = obj['body'].iter_lines()```: ```<generator object StreamingBody.iter_lines at 0x000001B8BC3BF270>```
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to save the file or loop over the file contents? If looping, that should work - try `for line in iterator:` `print(line)` and that will output the CSV for you

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Either way works for me. I tried looping over the content and I just got this: 
```b'hZ0'
b'KRh\xc1\xb4\x10:\x1f\xe6\xb7\xc3!\xc6\xc5\xc4\x03\xc2fz>1\xc0\x9f\xa9T\x06\xe5\xed\'\xd9\xb4\x9c\xb1\xcbv\x87\x00\x08\x9bi\x91-\xac \xda\x14\xd9\x02\xfcF\xad\'\x86\x1d]-z\x06\x84\x84\xcc\x8f\xe1\xc2\xf7\xbb\x13\xe4"\xbf\xf5m\xc7\xd7UT\x0b\xb8S\xb4\x06U\x01\x12wi\xfd($\x08\xa27\x04P\x94\x18,\xe5\xb6\x1c\x9a\x93\xdc\x16\x94\x7f\x9b\xa4\xa2\xf8$\xc7\xe2\xc4`\x813S\xb7'
b"?`Y\x1e'Q\x1c\xfaq\xca?\xea\xfa\xe9"``` (This is a part of the output)

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592700/4800344

Answer (score 1):

This happens if your string has non **`ASCII`** characters encoded in it and it is unable to decode with **`UTF-8`** (may happen if needed to use other encodings). In such a scenario, you need to use the encoding **`windows-1252`**.

The below solution works fine for me. By default, it tries to decode with **`UTF-8`** as it is recommended to use this encoding over others. If it gets an error while decoding then it tries with **`windows-1252`**.

```
message = 'some message with special characters'
try:
    return message.decode('utf-8')
except:
    return message.decode('windows-1252')
```

Now you can even encode it back with **`UTF-8`**.