# Python 'yield' statements cause JSON not serializable errors in LAMBDA AWS test case

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, lambda

I'm learning how to use Python in the Amazon AWS Lambda service.  I'm trying to read characters from an S3 object, and write them to another S3 object.  I realize I can copy the S3 object to a local tmp file, but I wanted to "stream" the S3 input into the script, process and output, without the local copy stage if possible.  I'm using code from this [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624900/how-can-i-use-boto-to-stream-a-file-out-of-amazon-s3-to-rackspace-cloudfiles) (Second answer) that suggests a solution for this.

This code contains two "yield()" statements which are causing my otherwise working script to throw a "generator is noto JSON serializable" error.
I'm trying to understand why a "yield()" statement would throw this error.  Is this a Lambda environment restriction, or is this something specific to my code that is creating the serialization issue.  (Likely due to using an S3 file object?).

Here is my code that I run in Lambda.  If I comment out the two yield statements it runs but the output file is empty.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import uuid
import boto3
import re

print('Loading IO function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

# Get the object from the event and show its content type
inbucket  = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
outbucket = "outlambda"
inkey     = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
outkey    = "out" + inkey
try:
    infile = s3.get_object(Bucket=inbucket, Key=inkey)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(inkey, bucket))
    raise e

    tmp_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), "tmp.txt")
#   upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

    with open(tmp_path,'w') as out:
        unfinished_line = ''
        for byte in infile:
             byte = unfinished_line + byte
             #split on whatever, or use a regex with re.split()
             lines = byte.split('\n')
             unfinished_line = lines.pop()
             for line in lines:
                  out.write(line)
                  yield line          # This line causes JSON error if uncommented
             yield unfinished_line    # This line causes JSON error if uncommented
    #
    # Upload the file to S3
    #
    tmp = open(tmp_path,"r")
    try:
       outfile = s3.put_object(Bucket=outbucket,Key=outkey,Body=tmp)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       print('Error putting object {} from bucket {} Body {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(outkey, outbucket,"tmp.txt"))
       raise e

    tmp.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is formatted correctly?  Specifically is the 'with open' block really inside the exception handling code?

Comment: Thanks, I found several other significant issues with this code.  I will look at that as well.  (Missed that one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function includes `yield` is actually a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), whereas the lambda handler needs to be a [function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html) that optionally returns a json-serializable value.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  If I encapsulate the function call then, I should be able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lei Shi for answering the specific point I was asking about.
Also Thanks to FujiApple for pointing out a missed coding mistake in the original code.
I was able to develop a solution without using yield that seemed to work copying the input file to output.  But with Lei Shi and FujiApples comments I was able to modify that code to create a sub function, called by the lambda handler which could be a generator.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import uuid
import boto3
import re
print('Loading IO function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def processFile( inbucket,inkey,outbucket,outkey):
    try:
        infile = s3.get_object(Bucket=inbucket, Key=inkey)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(inkey, bucket))
        raise e

    inbody   = infile['Body']
    tmp_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), "tmp.txt")
#   upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

    with open(tmp_path,'w') as out:
        unfinished_line = ''
        bytes=inbody.read(4096)
        while( bytes ):
             bytes = unfinished_line + bytes
             #split on whatever, or use a regex with re.split()
             lines = bytes.split('\n')
             print ("bytes %s" % bytes)
             unfinished_line = lines.pop() 
             for line in lines:  
                  print ("line %s" % line)
                  out.write(line)
                  yield line     # if this line is commented out uncomment the     unfinished line if() clause below
             bytes=inbody.read(4096)
#       if(unfinished_line):
#                 out.write(unfinished_line) 
    #
    # Upload the file to S3
    #
    tmp = open(tmp_path,"r")
    try:
       outfile = s3.put_object(Bucket=outbucket,Key=outkey,Body=tmp)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       print('Error putting object {} from bucket {} Body {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(outkey, outbucket,"tmp.txt"))
       raise e

    tmp.close()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    inbucket  = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    outbucket = "outlambda"
    inkey     = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']   ['key'].encode('utf8'))
    outkey    = "out" + inkey

    processFile( inbucket,inkey,outbucket,outkey)
```

I'm posting the solution which uses yield in a sub "generator" function.  Without the "yield" the code misses the last line, which was picked up by the if clause commented out.