# What is the best way to split a big file into small size files and send it to github using requests module POST/PUT method in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests

My requirement is to split a big file (e.g. 500MB)size into small files (50MB) in python.

What are the modules i can use in python to achieve this?

**For eg.**
*I have a file of 500MB size i want to split that file into 10 50 MB files and send it to an API*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any external modules. (In fact, you don't need to even `import` anything.)

This would chop up `large_file.dat` into 50-megabyte pieces and write them to disk – but you could just as well replace the file writing with whatever API call you need.

```
filename = "large_file.dat"
chunk_size = 50_000_000  # bytes; must fit in memory
chunk_num = 1

with open(filename, "rb") as input_file:
    while True:
        chunk = input_file.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:  # Nothing more to read, we've reached file end
            break
        with open(f"{filename}.{chunk_num:04d}", "wb") as output_file:
            output_file.write(chunk)
        chunk_num += 1
```

Comment: Thank you @AKX. That looks like a good solution to my problem. But it seems you have missed the for loop in the code you have shared

Comment: @Er.BikramKeshari Good catch. It was there in an earlier revision, and I simplified things and dropped it. Fixed now. :)

Comment: Hi @AKX, My requirement - reading a big file stored in a AWS S3 bucket and split that file into small chunks. And also i need to execute this snippet of code from a lambda function.

Do you have any idea how we can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661459/51685 shows you how to read an S3 file in chunks using boto3. Boto3 can also be used to write the smaller files back to S3.

Comment: AKX, really appreciate your quick response. I will go through the link. Thank you.