Read Large XML file from S3 Bucket and validate using XSD
I am creating a Lambda to validate an XML message against an XSD. I have all the python code working correctly on AWS, however as the file can be very large (around 2GB), I needed to find a way to chunk it up and validate each record against the XSD instead of the whole file.
I have managed to chunk it up record by record and got this working on AWS when processing a file with a couple of repeating "dataRecord" elements, however at the point of reading the large file from the bucket, I get "errorType": "MemoryError".
Here is an example of what the XML looks like, where "dataRecord" is the repeating structure that I need to validate against the XSD:
<root>
  <header>
    <fieldA>4ABC</fieldA>
  </header>
  <body>
    <dataRecordList>
      <dataRecord>
        <recordHeader>
          <type>ABC</type>
        </recordHeader>
      </dataRecord>
      <dataRecord>
        <recordHeader>
          <type>ABC</type>
        </recordHeader>
      </dataRecord>
    </dataRecordList>
  </body>
  <trailer>
    <records>1000</totalRecords>
  </trailer>
</root>

Here is the code that is erroring in the Lambda with "MemoryError":
xml_file = s3.get_object(Bucket="BucketName", Key="FileName")['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

Is there a way to retrieve records from the file without trying to bring the full file into memory?
(Disclaimer: New to Python :-D )

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661459/51685 – tl;dr: don't call .read().decode() (which will read all of the file into memory, then decode it from bytes to a string).

Great thanks, I'll have a look at that post. Much appreciated :-)

Using the iterparse function, I was able to process the large file from an S3 bucket without consuming much memory. I processed a 3.4GB XML file and the Lambda only used 248MB.
Here is the code, where the schema is for the full message which included a header and a trailer element. So these were added to each repeating datarecord before the record was then validated against the XSD.
import json
from lxml import etree
import datetime
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3') 

def lambda_handler(event, context):


bucket = 'my.bucket'
prefix = ""
xml_file_name = 'SOME_XML_FILE.xml'
xsd_file_name = 'SOME_SCHEMA.xsd'

valid_records = 0
invalid_records = 0

start = datetime.datetime.now()

print("Start Time:", start)

try:
    xml_root_open = "<root>"
    xml_root_close = "</root>"
    xml_header = "<header></header>"
    xml_drl_open = "<body><dataRecordList>"
    xml_drl_close = "</dataRecordList></body>"
    xml_trailer = "<trailer><totalRecords>0</totalRecords></trailer>"
    
    xml_top = xml_root_open + xml_header + xml_drl_open
    xml_bottom = xml_drl_close + xml_trailer + xml_root_close
    
    print("Get XML File")
    xml_file = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=xml_file_name)['Body']
    
    print("Get XSD File")
    xsd_content = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=xsd_file_name)['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    
    print("Parse Schema")
    xsd_doc = etree.fromstring(xsd_content.encode())
    xsd = etree.XMLSchema(xsd_doc)
    
    print("About to start loop")
    
    count = 0
    
    for event, elem in etree.iterparse(xml_file):
        if event == 'end':
            if elem.tag == 'dataRecord':
                # print("Found a Data Record!!")
                count+=1        
                
                dataRecord = etree.tostring(elem, encoding='unicode')
                # print(dataRecord)
                
                single_dr = xml_top + dataRecord + xml_bottom

                xml_doc = etree.fromstring(single_dr.encode())
                
                # Validating Record against XSD
                if not xsd.validate(xml_doc):
                    invalid_records = invalid_records + 1
                    # invalid record, print error
                    print(xsd.error_log)
            
                else:
                    # Valid Record
                    valid_records = valid_records + 1
                    

                elem.clear()
    
    print("Number of Data Records")
    print(count)
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise e

end = datetime.datetime.now()

print("End Time: ", end)
print("VALID RECORDS: ", str(valid_records))
print("INVALID RECORDS: ", str(invalid_records))

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda! Test')
}

